# How to show newsletter checkbox on new order page (admin)

Tags: magento

Cam we show newsletter check-box on order creation page in admin ? I noticed the xml code in sale.xml( app\design\adminhtml\default\default\layout ) file but don't why magento is not showing it on order creation page.Is there any

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>

   <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_newsletter" template="sales/order/create/abstract.phtml" name="newsletter">
       <block type="adminhtml/sales_order_create_newsletter_form" template="sales/order/create/newsletter/form.phtml" name="form" />
   </block>

</adminhtml_sales_order_create_index>
```